# Scheduler doesn't work in vTiger

Tags: cron, vtiger

I am an intern on a company in Malta. The company has just made a big change from sugarCRM to vTigerCRM. Now we have a problem with the scheduler. What we want is, when a mail is entered it should automatically get synced with the organisations and contacts (I can link them when I click on the "SCAN NOW" button of the mailconverter). But I want it automatically.

But my cron files are not getting updated.

I installed a cron on the linux server with the code below:

```
*/15 * * * * sh /vtiger_root/cron/vtigercron.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I adapt code the PHP_SAPI and I added the permissions on the proper files. But still. (as we speak my schedule task for the mail is at 1)

So every 15 minutes the vtigercron.sh is supposed to run vtigercron.php. But it doesn't happen. When I run vtigercron manually every things works fine. (The scheduler cron states get updated) but not with the cron file on the server.

Can somebody please be my hero?

Comment: You might need to start by changing sh to /bin/sh (or whatever your path to sh is).

Comment: You miss the user:  */15 *  * * *   root    sh  /var/www/html/vtigercrm/cron/vtigercron.sh

Answer (score 0):

In our crontab -

```
(sudo) vim /etc/crontab
```

I scheduled the job like this:

```
*/15 *  * * *   webdaemon   /bin/bash /var/www/vtigercrm6/cron/vtigercron.sh
```

Are you getting any errors in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages or whichever system log that your OS uses?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial actually works: https://www.easycron.com/cron-job-tutorials/how-to-set-up-cron-job-for-vtiger-crm

A simpler way:
In the file `vtigercron.php`, change the line

```
if(vtigercron_detect_run_in_cli() || (isset($_SESSION["authenticated_user_id"]) &&  isset($_SESSION["app_unique_key"]) && $_SESSION["app_unique_key"] == $application_unique_key)){
```

to

```
if(vtigercron_detect_run_in_cli() || ($_REQUEST["app_unique_key"] == $application_unique_key) || (isset($_SESSION["authenticated_user_id"]) &&  isset($_SESSION["app_unique_key"]) && $_SESSION["app_unique_key"] == $application_unique_key)){
```

and then use

```
http://www.example.com/vtigercron.php?app_unique_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

as cron job URL.

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:** You may find your `app_unique_key` in `config.inc.php` (look for `$application_unique_key` in it).
Please replace `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` in the URL above with the 32-chars `$application_unique_key` you find in `config.inc.php`, and `www.example.com` with your vtiger install location.